# Handling connection failures during JmsTemplate.send with IBM MQ

Tags: java, spring, jms, ibm-mq

I am using spring framework send method to send the message to IBM queue. With `CachingConnectionFactory`, `reconnectOnException` is set to true. We observed two incidents where during regular load, MQ server went down abruptly and send operation started throwing `MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN code:2009 (Expected)`. But even after the server was up, send was still failing and upon tomcat restart issue got fixed. To handle this scenario we modified send operation to have retry logic as shown in Snippet #2.
Here I am doing explicit resetConnection to make sure that once the server is up send will pass.

**Question 1 :** With this new code there is considerable wait time for each sender thread causing other application issue. 70% of Threads are blocked at below point with an average waiting time of 8 minutes. How can this waiting time be reduced?

**Question 2 :** Is there any better way to handle the failures after MQ comes up? We have `receonnectOptions` set but that did not help.

> Code snippet #1 is used to initialize Connection factory.
>
> Code snippet #2 modified send logic with retry and point where threads
>   are blocked.
>
> Code snippet #3 is exceptions we saw after MQ was up. After tomcat restart, send worked fine. Due to this issue fix in snippet #2 was
>   proposed.
>
> **Snippet #2: Modified send with retry logic.**

```
    public void send(final Destination destination, final MessageCreator messageCreator) {

        try {

            jmsTemplate.send(destination, messageCreator);
            LOGGER.info("message sent to destination: {}...", destination);

        } catch (JmsException jmsException) {

            // Check if exception is specific for connection issue
            if (isConnectionSpecificException(jmsException)) {
                if (resetConnectionLock.tryLock(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
                    // Reset connection
                    cachingConnectionFactory.resetConnection();
                    cachingConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
                    cachingConnectionFactory.setSessionCacheSize(jmsContextResolver.getSendSessionCacheSize());
                    jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(cachingConnectionFactory);

                }

            }
            // Try resend
            jmsTemplate.send(destination, messageCreator);

        }
    }
}
```

> With above code, Threads are blocked here for 8-10 minutes:

```
org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory$SharedConnectionInvocationHandler.localStop(SingleConnectionFactory.java:640)
at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory$SharedConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(SingleConnectionFactory.java:577)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy122.close(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.jms.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.releaseConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:80)
```

> Snippet #1:

```
final JmsFactoryFactory jmsFactoryFactory = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);
final JmsConnectionFactory imqConnectionFactory = jmsFactoryFactory.createConnectionFactory();
imqConnectionFactory.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, brokerInfo.getHost());
imqConnectionFactory.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, Integer.valueOf(brokerInfo.getPort()));
imqConnectionFactory.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, brokerInfo.getChannel());
imqConnectionFactory.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
imqConnectionFactory.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, brokerInfo.getQueueMgrName());
// ALSO TRIED WITH CLIENTRECONNECTOPTIONS SET. BUT DID NOT HELP.
```

> Snippet #3:

```
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2009' ('MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN').
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:203) ~[com.ibm.mqjms-8.0.0.4.jar:8.0.0.4 - p800-004-151017]
```

How can this waiting time be reduced. Is there a better way for retry logic?

Comment: What is the `HBINT` setting in the `SVRCONN` channel you connect to? You can respond by typing a comment in the box under this comment and clicking "Add Comment".

Comment: Hi @JoshMc is this a configuration defined in **mqclient.ini** ? Trying to contact my MQ team to get the file content.

Comment: No it is a queue manager config on the channel that you connect to.

Comment: Value for `HBINT` setting in `SVRCONN` channel is `300`. Values of other configs are as below:                                                                                                          `CHLTYPE=SVRCONN
COMPHDR=NONE
COMPMSG=NONE
DESCR=N/A
DISCINT=0
HBINT=300
KAINT=AUTO
MAXINST=999999999
MAXINSTC=999999999
MAXMSGL=4194304
MONCHL=QMGR
SHARECNV=10
SSLCAUTH=REQUIRED
SSLCIPH=N/A
SSLPEER=N/A
TRPTYPE=TCP`

Comment: With `HBINT(300)` the Receive timeout will be 360 seconds (6 minutes).  So from the last time your client received a messages from the queue manager, if it does not see something for 360 seconds it will timeout the connection with a 2009 (`MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN`).  If any normal traffic is sent to the queue manager during that time the client will not send a heart beat but if no traffic is sent to the queue manager for 300 seconds the client will send a heart beat.  So when you see the connection time out depends on the last time the queue manager sent to you.

Comment: So for example if the queue manager sent you a response to something the client did (`MQPUT`) for example 290 seconds before you issued the next `MQPUT`, but by that time the network connection was broken, you would notice the break in about 70 seconds, if however the queue manager just responded to a MQPUT and then 10 seconds later you issued another MQPUT and the connection was broken in between you would take 350 seconds to notice the break.

Comment: If the TCP layer actually provides the client back with feed back that the connection broke you will know sooner, but if something in between you and the server broke the connection (like a firewall or load balander), or the server went down, the the client would not get immediate feedback and the Heartbeats and receive timeout would determine this.

Comment: The calculate is if `HBINT` is less than 60 seconds, the receive timeout is 2x`HBINT`, if the `HBINT` is greater than or equal to 60 seconds, the receive timeout is `HBINT`+60.  JMS applications negotiate to the `SVRCONN`s `HBINT` value unless the JMS points to a CCDT in which case the highest value of HBINT between the SVRCONN and the CCDT's `CLNTCONN` channel definition is negotiated.

Comment: For JMS applications such as yours a good recommendation is to set the `SVRCONN`s `HBINT` to a much lower than the default value.  I have found 15 seconds work good, this will give a receive timeout of 30 seconds which is much more reasonable than 360 seconds.

Comment: If this info is helpful I can write up an answer for you to accept, let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JoshMc. I will test by changing `HBINT` settings. Do you think with changed value of `HBINT` , retry logic (snippet #2) will give more resiliency?

Comment: I think it would.  But you did mention 8 minutes not 6 minutes like would be expected based on `HBINT(300)`, I'm not sure how to resolve that if it was truly 8 minutes and not 6 minutes.

Comment: Along with `HBINT`, whether TCP connection timeout settings should be reduced ? `System.setProperty('com.ibm.mq.cfg.TCP.Connect_Timeout', 'X')` but could there be other implication of changing this value as well. e.g. Initial connection time could be longer when tomcat comes up and handshake is happening, Its valid to have longer TCP timeout in this case.

Comment: That setting is only on the initial connect to the queue manager and does not impact once a connection is already established.  If you think you are hitting this then it could be good to set, I have in the past set this to 30 seconds.

Comment: Thanks @JoshMc This is worked for me!!